# Google App Script - getValues from Range bug

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Spreadhsheet, if I have column names "org", "net" or "com" this values can't be retrieved with the Range.getValues function.

You can see this in my screenshots :

[image]

[image]

Are these column names reserved or is it a real Google App Script bug ?

Thank you.

Comment: It appears that the bug is in the listing of the individual array items. As you have shown just above in the 2d array and the row array the items are present. Have you tried writing this array back to a sheet to see if those items are included?

Comment: @ScampMichael They are retrieved and work perfectly with `for..in` loops, you'll never see a bug in your application then, but could miss something in the debugger...

Comment: @Kriggs Agreed. it is not in fact that the items cannot be retrieved as stated by the original post but that they are not being displayed properly in the debugger. A bug report about the debugger might be in order

Answer (score 0):

The problem is limited to the debugger display. All datas / values are retrieved and available (for...in) etc...

Thank you for your input.